# Error when running the flutter pub get command

Tags: flutter, git

when executing the flutter pub get command, I get the following error.

```
Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror https://github.com/Test/test.git /Users/user/.pub-cache/git/cache/test-e3750ea6bfc4e9b45a0923`
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/user/.pub-cache/git/cache/test-e3750ea6bfc4e9b45a0923'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
exit code: 128
```

That is, the problem is when I try to get a package using git like this:

file pubspec.yaml

```
  test:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Test/test.git
```

I specified the username and email for git through the console

Please help me, I have already tried everything and nothing helps(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it as follows: I manually copied this library as a new project via `git clone`. It was copied and then I re-launched the `flutter pub get` command in the old project and everything worked successfully

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are doing this from within Android Studio?
Go to File -> Settings -> Git
And then in the bottom check the Credentials Helper check box.

Comment: I already have this check box, but it still doesn’t help(

Comment: @Happy have you restarted the IDE after you checked it?